# T-SQL - get distinct columns from table with multiple columns with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

MS SQL 2014 using T-SQL

I have a linked server to an Oracle server that has several tables and views that contain multiple column wit the same name.  The values within the columns contain the same data.

```
SELECT
SERVER_NAME,
SERVER_NAME,
SERVER_NAME,
IP_ADDRESS,
IP_ADDRESS,
IP_ADDRESS,
IP_ADDRESS,
PHY_LOCATION,
PHY_LOCATION,
PHY_LOCATION,
OS_VERSION,
OS_VERSION
FROM SVR_TABLE
```

Is there a query I can execute that will give me the distinct column name from a table?  I'm trying to avoid going into each table and manually putting the distinct columns into a table.

```
SELECT
SERVER_NAME,
IP_ADDRESS,
PHY_LOCATION,
OS_VERSION
INTO [SQL_SVR_DB].[dbo].[SVR_TABLE]
FROM [ORACLE_SVR]..[SCHEMA_NAME].[SVR_TABLE]
```

Comment: Tables and views cannot have more than one column with the same name.

Comment: maybe aliasing your columns would help ? Look into Information_schema is you just want column names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second query that you have provided I think what you're looking for is *Aliases*.

Wikipedia defines SQL Aliases as:

> "An alias is a feature of SQL that is supported by most, if not all,
>   relational database management systems (RDBMSs). Aliases provide
>   database administrators, as well as other database users, with the
>   ability to reduce the amount of code required for a query, and to make
>   queries simpler to understand. In addition, aliasing can be used as an
>   obfuscation technique to protect the real names of database fields."

You can read more about it here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29

The query you are looking for will need to br written as :

```
SELECT      SERVER_NAME,
            IP_ADDRESS,
            PHY_LOCATION,
            OS_VERSION
FROM        [SQL_SVR_DB].[dbo].[SVR_TABLE] sqlTable
INNER JOIN  [ORACLE_SVR].[SCHEMA_NAME].[SVR_TABLE] oraTable
ON          sqlTable.ColumnName = oraTable.ColumnName
```